# Copying existing rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How do I go about doing the following?

I am using the following query to get a specific users tab ids:

```
select id
from intranet.dbo.tabs
where cms_initials = @user
order by id asc
```

which might return the following ids

```
4
5
6
7
```

I now want to insert the rows from the following query:

```
select tabs_id, widgets_id, sort_column, sort_row
from intranet.dbo.columns c
inner join intranet.dbo.tabs t on c.tabs_id = t.id
where t.is_default = 1
```

But use the ids from the first query to replace the tab ids

so if the second query originally returns tabs_id's as

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
```

I should end up with

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
6
7
7
```

Is this possible with sql server 2005 without using stored procedures?

So far I have

```
insert into intranet.dbo.columns ( tabs_id, widgets_id, sort_column, sort_row )
select tabs_id, widgets_id, sort_column, sort_row
    from intranet.dbo.columns c
    inner join intranet.dbo.tabs t on c.tabs_id = t.id
    where t.is_default = 1
```

But this just copies everything as is, I need to do that, but replace the ids in the copied rows.

Comment: I think you are looking for a subquery?

Comment: I have added my current query to the end of my question.  I am not sure how to get the very first query into the last query.

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't make any sense.  In  your desired output, how do you get `0, 1, 2, 3` if they aren't in the first query and as you say you are **replacing**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses [common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx). A and B are your original queries ranked by tab order. A and B are then joined by tab ranking and inserted.

```
USE intranet

;WITH A AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS tab_ranking
        , id
    FROM dbo.tabs
    WHERE cms_initials = @user
),
B AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tabs_id) AS tab_sequence
        , tabs_id, widgets_id, sort_column, sort_row
    FROM dbo.columns
    WHERE tabs_id IN (SELECT t.id FROM dbo.tabs t WHERE t.is_default = 1)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.columns (tabs_id, widgets_id, sort_column, sort_row)
SELECT a.id, b.widgets_id, b.sort_column, b.sort_row
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.tab_ranking = A.tab_ranking
```